# PIC16F UART Receives only the first byte

Tags: pic, uart, communication, rs232, pic16f

I'm currently working on a PIC16F18855, I'm trying to set up the communication part.

My setup is as follows:
A PCB connected to my computer via a TTL232 cable.
The PIC16F18855 is clocked at 32Mhz, the communication pins are RC2 for TX and RC7 for RX, communication speed 115 200 bauds.

My aim is to send the following frame every second to the PCB: 0x01; 0x09; 0x0A. When I debug, I see that in my interrupts I only receive 0x01 in a loop. I connected an oscilloscope to the RX pin of my PIC and got this signal, as you can see in the photo.

[image: Signal 0x01 0x09 0x0A]

Below I'll detail my code as best I can:

*Main.c*

```
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with OSCFRQ= 32 MHz and CDIV = 1:1)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; i/o or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (FSCM timer disabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR pin is Master Clear function)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-Power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out reset enable bits (Brown-out reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9V on LF, and 2.45V on F Devices)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR.)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly by software)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a reset)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31// WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // WDT operating mode (WDT Disabled, SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7// WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required)
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC      // WDT input clock selector (Software Control)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // UserNVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config SCANE = available// Scanner Enable bit (Scanner module is available for use)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/Vpp pin function is MCLR.)

// CONFIG5
#pragma config CP = OFF         // UserNVM Program memory code protection bit (Program Memory code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // DataNVM code protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.


void main(void) {
    
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    
    while(1){
        
        if(f_1ms){
            f_1ms = 0;
            Gestion_UART();
        }
    }
}
```

*clock.c*

```
void CLOCK_Initialize(void)
{
    // HFINTOSC = 32Mhz Nominal;
    OSCCON1bits.NOSC = 0x03;
    OSCCON1bits.NDIV = 0x00;
    
    OSCCON3 = 0x00;
    
    OSCEN = 0x40; 
    
    OSCFRQ = 0x06;
    // HFINTOSC = Nominal
    OSCTUNE = 0x00;
 
}
```

*pin.c*

```
void PIN_MANAGER_Initialize(void)
{
       /*
    LATx registers
    */
    LATA = 0x0;
    LATB = 0x0;
    LATC = 0x0;
    
    /*
    TRISx registers
    */
    TRISA = 0b01010110;
    TRISB = 0b11111111;
    TRISC = 0b10111011;

    /*
    ANSELx registers
    */
    ANSELA = 0x00;
    ANSELB = 0x00;
    ANSELC = 0x00;

    /*
    WPUx registers
    */
    WPUA = 0x0;
    WPUB = 0x0;
    WPUC = 0x18;


    /**
    ODx registers
    */
   
    ODCONA = 0x0;
    ODCONB = 0x0;
    ODCONC = 0x0;
    /**
    SLRCONx registers
    */
    SLRCONA = 0xFF;
    SLRCONB = 0xFF;
    SLRCONC = 0xFF;
    /**
    INLVLx registers
    */
    INLVLA = 0xFF;
    INLVLB = 0xFF;
    INLVLC = 0xFF;

   /**
    IOCx registers 
    */
    IOCAP = 0x0;
    IOCAN = 0x0;
    IOCAF = 0x0;
    IOCBP = 0x0;
    IOCBN = 0x0;
    IOCBF = 0x0;
    IOCCP = 0x0;
    IOCCN = 0x0;
    IOCCF = 0x0;   
     
}

void PIN_MANAGER_IOC(void)
{
    
    PPSLOCK = 0x55;
    PPSLOCK = 0xAA;
    PPSLOCKbits.PPSLOCKED = 0;    
    
    RXPPS = 0x17; // Input RX1
    RC2PPS = 0X10; // Output TX1
    
    CCP1PPS = 0x08; // Input CCP1 Capture D?bit
    
    RA3PPS = 0x0A; // Output CCP2 PWM Bleu
    
    /* RC4 <-> SDA1 */
    RC4PPS = 0x15;
    SSP1DATPPS  = 0x14;  

    /* RC3 <-> SCL1 */    
    RC3PPS = 0x14;
    SSP1CLKPPS = 0x13;
    
    PPSLOCK = 0x55;
    PPSLOCK = 0xAA;    
    PPSLOCKbits.PPSLOCKED = 1;
    
}
```

*uart.c*

```
void UART_Initialize(void){
    //UART
    
    BAUD1CONbits.RCIDL = 1;
    BAUD1CONbits.SCKP = 0;
    BAUD1CONbits.WUE = 0;
    BAUD1CONbits.ABDEN = 0;
    BAUD1CONbits.BRG16 = 1;
    BAUD1CONbits.SCKP = 0;
            
    TX1STAbits.TX9 = 0;
    TX1STAbits.TXEN = 0;
    TX1STAbits.SYNC = 0;
    TX1STAbits.SENDB = 1;
    TX1STAbits.BRGH = 1;
    
    RC1STAbits.SPEN = 1;
    RC1STAbits.RX9 = 0;
    RC1STAbits.CREN = 1;
    RC1STAbits.FERR = 0;
    RC1STAbits.OERR = 0;
    
    //SP1BRG = 832; // 9600 bauds @32Mhz
    //SP1BRG = 767; //10K417 bauds @32Mhz
    SP1BRG = 68; // 115K2 bauds @32Mhz
    
    etape_it_uart = 0;
    etat_uart = 0;
}

unsigned char calcul_checksum(void) {
    unsigned char calcul;
    unsigned char i;

    calcul = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= t_tx[0]; i++) calcul += t_tx[i];
    
    return (calcul);
}

void Gestion_UART(void){

    switch (etat_uart) {
        case 0: // Attente reception trame
            if (etape_it_uart == 0) timeout_rx = 0;
            else if (rx_trame_ok) etat_uart = 10;
            else if (++timeout_rx > 10) {
                 //probleme de duree de reception => Init reception
                nb_octet_rx = 0;
                etape_it_uart = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 10: // Vérification du checksum
            if(calcul_checksum == t_rx[t_rx[0] + 1]) etat_uart = 20;
            else{
                etat_uart = 0;
                etape_it_uart = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

*Interrupt.c*

```
void INTERRUPT_Initialize(){
    //Timer 0
    T0CON0bits.T0EN = 1;
    T0CON0bits.T016BIT = 0;
    T0CON0bits.T0OUTPS = 0;
    
    T0CON1bits.T0CS = 3;
    T0CON1bits.T0ASYNC = 0;
    T0CON1bits.T0CKPS = 4;
    
    PIE0bits.TMR0IE = 1;   
    
    TMR0 = 6;
    
    PIE3bits.TXIE = 1; // Enabled interrupt UART TX  
    PIE3bits.RCIE = 1; // Enabled interrupt UART RX 
    
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; 
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}

void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{  
    if(PIR3bits.RCIF){
        t_rx[etape_it_uart] = RC1REG;
        etape_it_uart++;
        
        if(etape_it_uart > t_rx[0] + 1){
            etape_it_uart = 0;
            rx_trame_ok = true;
        }
        
        if(RC1STAbits.OERR)
        {
            RC1STAbits.CREN = 0;
            RC1STAbits.CREN = 1; 
        }
        
        PIR3bits.RCIF = 0;
    } 
    
    if(PIR3bits.TXIF){
        if (nb_octet_tx <= SIZE_TX_TRAME) {
            TX1REG = t_tx[nb_octet_tx];
            nb_octet_tx++;           
        } else {
            tx_trame_ok = 1;
            TX1STAbits.TXEN = 0;
        }    
    }
            
    if(PIR0bits.TMR0IF)
    {
        f_1ms = 1;
        
        if(cpt1ms++ >= 9){
            cpt1ms = 0;            
            f_10ms = 1;
            
            if (cpt10ms++ >= 9) {
                cpt10ms = 0;                
                f_100ms = 1;                
                
                if (cpt100ms++ >= 9) {
                    cpt100ms = 0;
                    f_1s = 1;
                    
                    if(cpt1s++ >= 2){
                        cpt1s = 0;
                        f_2s = 1;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }      
        
        TMR0 = 6;
        
        PIR0bits.TMR0IF=0;       // Clear timer interrupt flag
    }   
}
```

The process is as follows: Every ms I use the "Gestion_UART" function to check if an RX interrupt is raised and to manage if the frame transmission time is too long. In my RX interrupt I recover the bytes and when I've recovered everything I take action according to the frame received.

Thank you very much for your help.

**[EDIT]**

I put back the code in light version with only the communication.
I've also included 3 screenshots to explain my problem.

First screenshot, reception in the RX interrupt of the first byte, which is 0x01.
[image: first byte 0x01]

Second screenshot, 10ms timeout lifted.
[image: timeout]

Third screenshot, RX interrupt with timeout removed, reception of three 0x01 bytes instead of the 0x01 0x09 0x0A frame sent.
[image: without timeout]

**[EDIT2]**

So, following the advice in comment, I tried to send 3 bytes every second to my computer and I receive random data continuously, I add you the result seen by the oscilloscope:
[image: TX Data send when no debug mode]

On the other hand, when I'm in debug mode and I set breakpoints in the ISR on the TX part, I receive the right bytes on my computer.

Comment: @DaveTweed the OP is using the UART interrupt to save received bytes into a buffer (`t_rx`), and then checking that buffer every mSec.

Comment: What is your baud rate error?

Comment: @DaveTweed
Hello and thank you for your feedback.
I may have misspoken, I do use an interrupt for RX, where I store the received bytes in a buffer. 
The function I call every ms is to manage the timeout and process the information received.

Comment: @rdtsc 0.64% baud rate error

Comment: @DaveTweed
In my interrupt here :

`if(PIR3bits.RCIF){
        t_rx[etape_it_uart] = RC1REG;
        etape_it_uart++;
        
        if(etape_it_uart > t_rx[0] ){
            etape_it_uart = 0;
            rx_trame_ok = true;
        }
 `

I only receive one byte and the timeout starts after 10ms. I've tried removing this timeout function and I get an array composed of 0x01

Comment: I give up. You need to come up with a consistent story, and to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the behavior, as well as explain exactly what the difference is between what you expect to happen and what actually happens. If you're just looking for a code review, there's a separate SE site for that.

Comment: @DaveTweed
Sorry if I'm expressing myself badly. 
What I'm expecting is to receive a frame consisting of 3 bytes 0x01; 0x09; 0x0A sent from my computer.
What actually happens is that the RX interrupt is triggered and I receive the first byte 0x01 and then nothing.
I hope I've made myself clearer.

Comment: "A PCB connected to my computer via a TTL232 cable." Is the computer a regular windows/DOS PC? Does you cable convert from TTL232 to RS232?

Comment: Not related, but there is no code to clear PIR3bits.TXIF. Did you declare the variables used inside the ISR as volatile?

Comment: There may be a "number of stop bits" issue. The PC sends in 8N1 format, but the receiver may expect something else. Does it work if you send the 3 characters with a 50-100 µs gap in between? Did you verify the 1 ms timebase?

Comment: The best you can do to let us help you efficiently is to reduce your application to the minimal complete example that still shows the erroneous behaviour. I'm not going to wade through all your source... For example, since your µC does not transmit, omit that part. It does not use RS485, omit that, too. And so on.

Comment: @Rodo
Hello, the computer is an ordinary windows. The cable I'm using [link](https://docs.rs-online.com/588e/0900766b80d4cba6.pdf)

Comment: @Jens
Hi, I delete PIR3bits.TXIF in the uart.c file once all bytes are sent. I did not declare the variables as volatiles, could this have an impact?
I'll try to send the bytes with an interval.

Comment: @thebusybee
I've put the code back in a light version with only the communication and screenshots explaining my problem better.

Comment: If you allow tx empty interrupts, you must handle the flag in the ISR. Not using the volatile attribute invites demons and gremlins. Such problems are very hard to debug, just do it the proper way. Does the PC receive correct data from the MCU?

Comment: Please note that I am not familiar with the PIC processor, but every microcontroller I have worked with have separate interrupt vectors for each interrupting device.  From the OP's code, it is unclear whether ISR() is the handler for the timer or the serial device.  The OP is processing both in ISR(), which just seems very odd to me.

Comment: @Jens
So, I followed your advice by managing the TX flag in the ISR and send 3 bytes every second to my computer and I receive random data continuously, I add you the result seen by the oscilloscope in edit.
On the other hand, when I'm in debug mode and I set breakpoints in the ISR on the TX part, I get the right bytes...

Comment: @SteveMathwig
Indeed I handle both in the same ISR, communication and timer. On another project using another PIC16F, I have the same method and haven't seen any problems, but maybe you're right it's something I need to look into.

Comment: @Benito - I suggest you spend some more time reading the datasheet on this part.  Two things I noticed after a quick look at the datasheet: a) you cannot clear RCIF by writing to it, it is cleared when RC1REG is read and there are no unread characters left, and b) the TXIF bit is always set when the transmitter is idle, you will probably want to qualify with TXEN.  I don't think it was your intent to constantly take the TXIF path on every interrupt.